# How to use multiprocessing in Python using Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to speed up some processes and was trying to use multiple cores for a Python script.  I was trying to get the framework down before I applied it to what I was doing.  So far, I have something that works, but it has two shortcomings: 
1)It outputs information from each iteration - I just want the final value
2)It only speeds things up a little bit (about 60% of the original time when I was testing it), which is better, but not a game changer.

Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import itertools
start = time.clock()
processes = []
output_list = [] 

def all_combinations(count_arg):
    returns_list = []
    for i in range(1,count_arg+1):
        tmp_comb = list(itertools.combinations(range(0,count_arg),i))
        for tmp_tup in tmp_comb:
            returns_list.append(tmp_tup)
    return returns_list
def worker(num):   
    tmp_output = len(all_combinations(num))
    return tmp_output
if __name__ =='__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(8)
    num_list = range(24)
    output_list2 = pool.map(worker, num_list)   
    pool.close()
    pool.join       
elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
results = output_list
print elapsed
```

This is what I was using as the non-multiprocessing case:

```
import time
import itertools
start = time.clock()
processes = []
def all_combinations(count_arg):
    returns_list = []
    for i in range(1,count_arg+1):
        tmp_comb = list(itertools.combinations(range(0,count_arg),i))
        for tmp_tup in tmp_comb:
            returns_list.append(tmp_tup)
    return returns_list

def worker(num,output):
    """thread worker function"""
    tmp_output = len(all_combinations(num))
    return tmp_output

for i in range(24):
    processes.append(worker(i,"hi"))

elapsed = (time.clock() - start)

print len(processes)
print elapsed
```

Comment: Weird bug - I was trying to fix the lack of code blocks and the code-block wasn't working properly. thoughts?

Comment: It's because of the list of shortcomings (1. , 2. , etc.)

Comment: @user3467349 -- markdown (or maybe just SO's variant) has some strange behaviors when dealing with code that immediately follows an unordered or ordered list.  The trick is to just insert some "meaningful junk" between the list and the code block.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I'm trying to fix it...

Comment: You just needed another blank line at the end of your list.

Comment: From what I see so far you're recurrently generating large lists of tuples, if performance is an issue than you probably want to consider `numpy`

Comment: what does this code do?

Comment: Thanks for the insight - that is definitely helpful.  This specific program is just a process that eats up time, though, and not necessarily meant to be efficient.  I was just using it to see how much improvement there was when using multiprocessing.

Comment: python will probably not improve that much from multiprocessing in terms of computational speeds- It's more useful for various tasks that need to be done concurrently from my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating a lot of lists just to throw them away ... I'd change `all_combinations` into a generator:

```
def all_combinations(count_arg):
    for i in range(1,count_arg+1):  # xrange on python2.x
        # yield from itertools.combinations(...) on python3.3+
        for comb in itertools.combinations(range(0,count_arg),i)):
            yield comb
```

Now `worker` needs to change to get the number of items from the generator rather than a list...

```
def worker(num):
    return sum(1 for _ in all_combinations(num))
```

These changes are mostly just aesthetic -- You'll likely not notice a large speedup one way or another (although I could be wrong, as with anything, you never know until you profile ...).

Now that that's out of the way, on to your *real* questions...

> 1) It outputs information from each iteration ...

Of course `multiprocessing.Pool.map` will give you one result per process in the pool.  In this case you'll get 24 (one for each `num_list`).  Fortunately, the "reduce" stage of this is really easy -- Since each element returned by the worker is just a partial sum, you can just get the sum of the output list:

```
print sum(output_list2)
```

> 2) It only speeds things up a little bit...

This is because your algorithm doesn't scale well.  You'll only ever be as fast as your slowest running worker -- And your workers don't all execute in similar times.  Note that as the numbers get higher you're doing more and more combinations in a given worker.  This makes the workers for higher numbers (e.g. 24) much more expensive to compute than the worker for lower numbers (e.g. 12).  To get better speedups, you need better load balancing.

Comment: Thank you for providing some improvements on the setup as well as addressing the original questions.

Comment: I actually wanted the sum of the time, so defining and printing elapsed within the if statement solved that.